# Regular expression with PHP to replace newlines

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace all the \n in a json string with a double pipe ||. Here is an example of a string :

```
{"comment":"test1
test2
test3"}';
```

Here is the regex I have done :

```
preg_match('/"comment":"(([^\n\t\r"]*)([\n\t\r]*))+"/', $a, $t);
```

The result of this preg_match is

```
Array
(
    [0] => "comment":"test1
test2
test3"
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
)
```

I can't find what is wrong with my regexp.

Do I need a recursive pattern (?R) ?

Thanks.

Comment: if you want to replace `\n` chars then why you use `preg_match` ?

Comment: Actually I don't want to replace all the newlines but only newlines in the comment. If you have a || just after {, the php function json_decode will encounter a problem.

Comment: @Hicham: cf my answer: decode the string, change the `comment` value, and encode the data again. It's the easiest _and_ safest way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_replace function like below. I assumed that your input have balanced paranthesis.

```
preg_replace('~(?:"comment"[^\n]*|\G)\K\n([^{}\n]*)~', '||\1', $str)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jC3uR4/9)

Comment: what does [^{}] represent ? Every caracter which is not { or } ?

Comment: yep, match all the chars except `{` or `}`

Comment: And if I want to replace it only in the content of the comment  "comment":"HERE" I tried \n(?="comment":".*")

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: foo
{"comment":
"test1||test2||test3"}';
bar

Comment: because after I will have other argument unless comment and I want to replace only on the comment

Comment: The problem now is my server doesn't support the \K option, don't know why. Do you have an alternative ? I can't modify the pcre library on the server.

Comment: Interesting, but I have to do this preg_replace : preg_replace('~((?:"comment"[^\n]*|\G))\n([^{}\n"]*)~', '$1||$2', $json). Thanks a lot Avinash :)

Answer (score 0):

```
\n+(?=[^{]*})
```

You can simply use this.Replace with `||`.

```
$re = "/\\n+(?=[^{]*})/i";
$str = "{\"comment\":\"test1\n test2\n test3\"}'";
$subst = "||";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to replace all the newlines but only newlines in the comment. If you have a || just after {, the php function json_decode will encounter a problem.

Comment: @Hicham A newline is not allowed in a json value, they should all be replaced with `\n`. Then you can use json_decode() as said in the missing answer.